# Why does calling .Include() after a .Join() not work?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core

I have a DB structure which is not ideal, but I have coded it into EF like this:

```
[Table("Item")]
public class Item
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }  // An ItemTypeId of 1 means this row refers to an Article
    public int ItemId { get; set; }      // this refers to the Article primary key
}

[Table("Article")]
public class Article
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<SubArticle> SubArticles { get; set; }
}

[Table("SubArticle")]
public class SubArticle
{
    ...
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().Collection(_ => _.SubArticles).InverseReference(_ => _.Article).ForeignKey(_ => _.ArticleId);
```

What I want to do is get all articles (with the corresponding sub-articles) that belong to a specific category. I have this query which is working:

```
var result = await Context.Set<Item>()
       .Where(i => i.CategoryId == 200)
       .Where(i => i.ItemTypeId == 1)
       .Join(
           Context.Set<Article>().Include(a => a.SubArticles),
           i => i.ItemId,
           a => a.Id,
           (i,a) => a)
       .ToListAsync();

result.SubArticles.First(); // works
```

My question is why does this query not work:

```
var result = await Context.Set<Item>()
       .Where(i => i.CategoryId == 200)
       .Where(i => i.ItemTypeId == 1)
       .Join(
           Context.Set<Article>(),
           i => i.ItemId,
           a => a.Id,
           (i,a) => a)
       .Include(a => a.SubArticles)
       .ToListAsync();

result.SubArticles.First(); // error: result.SubArticles is null
```

Comment: How does the firs "worked" code can be worked, when your 'result' - is the LIST of 'item' and result.SubArticles is not a valid code in this case?

Comment: The result is not a list of Item it is a list of Article because of the .Join method.